# What is the difference between GU10 and GU10+C?

Tags: lighting

Is there a difference in the socket itself? I found that Amazon does not differentiate between the two. I searched online, but only got a lot of different answers, none of which seemed sufficiently solidly founded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, the -c just means "cover". Google "GU-10 vs GU-10-c"